# How to expand UIView and move other components when expanded

Tags: swift, uiview, move, expand

I have a view Controller that contains filter_View

[image: Filter_View]

and a tableView_Players

[image] .

When I press the button "Filter la recherche"

[image]

I want the Filter_View to expand this way

[image: Expanded view]

and results moving the tableview down

[image: Tableview moves down] .

How to do that ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add vertical spacing with upperview (Expanding view) ;  leading space , trailing space and bottom constraint with superview to the bottom view which you need to be adjusted.
So when ever a change occurs in the upper view , the changes may reflect over to the below view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AutoLayout, do following :

1) set vertical spacing from tableView to filterView.

2) set Height Constraint of filterView and set its outlet.

3) Initially that height constraint e.g. heightOfFilterview.constant = x

4) While clicking filter la button set heightOfFilterView.constant = y (Whatever you want).